# pyinstaller hooks never called

Tags: python, hook, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an EXE of a python program. The program is quite complex and cannot be listed here. I have some user defined modules, halfwave, halfwave.utils and halfwave.db. I need to create a hook for these modules, so I have made files hook-halfwave.py, hook-halfwave.db.py and halfwave.utils.py and put in a folder called hooks. In the program I import the modules

```
from halfwave import ...
from halfwave.utils import ...
from halfwave.db import ...
```

But the hook files are never called by the pyinstaller. I have tried setting hookspath in the Analysis structure of the spec file and set the --additional-hooks-path switch. If I put the hook files in the pyinstaller hooks path, they get called, but that is not a good option. What is the trick for making the pyinstaller call the hook files?

EDIT:
The command I run is

```
pyinstaller -y foo.spec
```

and the .spec file looks something like this

```
a = Analysis(['.\\src\\testfoo.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Data\\python\\testfoo'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath='.\\hooks\\',
         runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts, ...
```

Also tried using the --additional-hooks-dir switch, but that makes no difference.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the full command line you are trying to execute, including the relevant switch for including your hook files?

Comment: Have added the information about command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `hookspath` argument should be a `list` of paths, as follows:

```
a = Analysis(['.\\src\\testfoo.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Data\\python\\testfoo'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=['.\\hooks\\'],
         runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts, ...
```